# Backbonejs: How to unbind collection bindings when a view is removed?

Tags: backbone.js

I've got a backbonejs application with two view. It kind of looks like this:

```
<body>
  <header></header>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

Every time a view is loaded the app overwrites the current view by completely overwriting the contents of #content.

```
// Like this...
$('#content').html( new primaryView().render() );
// ...and this.
$('#content').html( new secondaryView().render() );
```

The application has a global collection.

```
App.Collection();
```

The secondary view modifies itself depending on the global collection. Therefor it binds a function to the 'add' event' on App.Collection in the views initialize function;

```
App.Collection.bind('add', function(){
    console.log('Item added');
});
```

Which result in my problem. Every time the secondary view is loaded a new function is binded to App.Collection's add event. If I go from the primary view to the secondary view three times, the function will fire three times everytime an item is added to App.Collection.

What am I doing wrong?
I can see how I would do it if there was an uninitialize function on views.
I can see how I could do it if I never removed a view once it was loaded.
I can see how I would do it if I could namespace events like in Jquery. (by unbinding before binding).

Comment: Just found an article by Derick Bailey. Sounds like a decent enough solution. http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generalize your problem quite a bit. Basically, you are writing an event-driven app, and in such app events should be taken care of.

Check out [this post](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/) to see a recommended way to work with event handlers in backbone.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, you can use `initialize` and `render` methods to handle different aspects of creating a view. For instance, you can put your binding inside the `initialize`

```
initialize: function() {
  App.Collection.bind('add', function(){
    this.view.render()
  });
}
```

which only fires when the view is created. This binds your `render` method to the add event. Then in your `render` method you can actually create the html.

This prevents the binding from happening every time you need to re-render.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Masondesu, but I went with Derick Baileys solution. I want to completely erase my views so they don't take up unnecessary memory.